# Probability of $d$ linearly independent vectors among $m$ over a finite ring

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative finite ring that is isomorphic to a direct product of fields. Typically, $R$ could be $R = \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ for $q = \prod_{i = 1}^\kappa p_i$ for distinct primes $p_i$, or $R = \mathcal{O}_K/q\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K$ is a number field, $\mathcal{O}_K$ its maximal order and $q$ an unramified prime integer, because both settings have a Chinese Remainder Theorem.

I want to determine (or lower bound) the probability that for $m \geq d$ uniformly random vectors of $R^d
$, there is a subset of $d$ of those vectors that are linearly independent over $R$.
Is there a result I am not aware of that would solve this problem ?

--

I know that for a finite field $\mathbb{F}$, this probability is given by $$\prod_{k = 0}^{d-1} \left(1 - \frac{1}{\vert\mathbb{F}\vert^{m - k}} \right)$$
My idea was that if $R$ is isomorphic to $\times_{i = 1}^{\kappa} \mathbb{F}_i$, then I could analyze the problem in each field $\mathbb{F}_i$ and conclude over $R$ by *recombining* everything with the isomorphism. This works when $m = d$ but when $m > d$ it is a little more problematic.
Indeed, if the $\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_m$ are the vectors over $R$ and $\mathbf{v}_1^i, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_m^i$ are their *coordinate* over $\mathbb{F}_i^d$, then it seems that the following scenario can happen:

- For each $i$ I have a set $S_i \subseteq \{1, \ldots, m\}$ of size $d$ such that $(\mathbf{v}_j^i)_{j \in S_i}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{F}_i$;
- $\cap_{i = 1}^\kappa S_i$ is of size strictly less than $d$.

in which case I cannot conclude this way.